# How to add job with trigger for running Quartz.NET scheduler instance without restarting server?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, quartz.net

Is it possible to add job with trigger for running Quartz.NET scheduler instance without restarting server?

Comment: Are you using RAM or ADO jobstore?

Comment: In my solution i have to connect with sql server.Because all job shedules directly store in the sql database.

Answer (score 8):

A fairly robust implementation with ADOJobStore is to have a custom table to store jobs and create a class that inherits from ISchedulerPlugin and IJob to create schedules for your job automatically.

Your config will look like this:

```
<add key="quartz.plugin.sqlquartzjobs.type" value="(JobSchedulerPlugin assembly path)" />
<add key="quartz.plugin.sqlquartzjobs.RescanCronExpression" value="0 0/5 * * * ?" /> //plugin should fire every five minutes
<add key="quartz.plugin.sqlquartzjobs.ConnectionString" value="(your connection string)" />
```

Your plugin/job class can look like this:

```
public class JobSchedulerPlugin : ISchedulerPlugin, IJob
{
        //Entry point for plugin, quartz server runs when it starts
        public void Initialize(string pluginName, IScheduler sched)
        {
            Name = pluginName;
            Scheduler = sched;
        }

        //Runs after Initialize()
        public void Start()
        {
                //schedule plugin as a job
            JobDataMap jobData = new JobDataMap();
            jobData["ConnectionString"] = ConnectionString;

            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create(this.GetType())
                .WithDescription("Job to rescan jobs from SQL db")
                .WithIdentity(new JobKey(JobInitializationPluginJobName, JobInitializationPluginGroup))
                .UsingJobData(jobData)
                .Build();

             TriggerKey triggerKey = new TriggerKey(JobInitializationPluginJobTriggerName, JobInitializationPluginGroup);

             ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                 .WithCronSchedule(ConfigFileCronExpression)
                 .StartNow()
                 .WithDescription("trigger for sql job loader")
                 .WithIdentity(triggerKey)
                 .WithPriority(1)
                 .Build();

             Scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
        }
}
```

Now JobSchedulerPlugin has entered a trigger into QRTZ_TRIGGERS that will fire every five minutes with highest priority. You can use it to load jobs from your custom table (let's call it QUARTZJOBS). QUARTZJOBS can contain information such as jobnames, assembly paths, dates, status, etc, anything that can be used to help you create triggers efficiently. It should also contain the cron expression to the job. This is what you can do when the trigger fires:

```
//Entry point of every job
public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
    Scheduler = context.Scheduler;

    JobCollection jobs = LoadJobs(context.JobDetail.JobDataMap["ConnectionString"].ToString());
    JobsWithTriggers jobTriggers = CreateTriggers(jobs);
    SchedulerJob(jobTriggers);
}

//You can use ADO.NET or an ORM here to load job information from the the table
//and push it into a class. 
protected JobCollection LoadJobs(string connectionString);

//In this class you can create JobDetails and ITriggers for each job
//and push them into a custom class
protected JobsWithTriggers CreateTriggers(jobs);

//Finally here you can schedule the jobs
protected void ScheduleJobs(jobstriggers)
```

In each of the classes above you can add custom validation for making sure triggers are handled appropriately if status or cron expression changes.

With this solution the server will never need to be restarted. The plugin/job class will scan the table and act accordingly.

Comment: "...load jobs from your custom table ...  jobnames, assembly paths, dates, status, etc..." New to Quartz.NET; it's my understanding that assemblies have to be in the same folder as the Quartz.NET runtime. But I'm intrigued by your claim otherwise and would like to implement--could you elaborate? Tx.

Comment: I'm not finding classes `JobCollection` or `JobsWithTriggers` in the Quartz.NET source--can you assist? Tx.

Comment: With this solution, will it be possible to update assemblies/delete jobs without restarting the server? I'm still confused as to your general architecture. Again, I'm brand-new to all of this yet. Documentation seems to be weak in general, best for basic 'getting-started' tips. Seems ol' Marko just can't please anybody, can he?  ;-)

Comment: OK, I've got it working with assemblies from external paths, using `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`. FYI once I get a better understanding of Quartz.NET, which hopefully won't take too long, I'm going to want to help Marko with documentation.

Comment: @InteXX As you've seen assemblies don't necessarily need to be in the same folder as long as you have a reference in the project. Quartz.NET loads them via reflection. Personally I put the assembly path in the QUARTZJOBS table and load it to the scheduler in the ScheduleJobs method. I have separate projects for my jobs in order to group them better, which is great for architecture.

Comment: @InteXX JobCollection and JobsWithTriggers are not in the Quartz.NET source, they are custom implementations. JobCollection are entries in the QUARTZJOBS table which LoadJobs method retrieves from database. CreateTriggers does some basic validation. For example I have an IsActive column. If it is set to false, the CreateTriggers method will delete any job triggers (via the API). If it is active and there is no trigger (or a different trigger is specified) it will add it to the table.

Comment: @InteXX You can delete jobs on the fly with the IsActive column on the QuartzJobs table (see answer above). Also do the same for assemblies. The next time the plugin fires it will take care of it. Documentation like you say is lacking for the more advanced features; this is generally a problem for open source- if you can expand it please do! :) Hope you've found this helpful (if so please upvote!) If you have any other questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Yes, these help very much, thanks. But I'm still a bit lost about what you're saying without seeing some complete code. Are you able to share a bit more? What's the best way--shall I post a new question?

Comment: @InteXX It's best that you post a new question- someone else may have a simpler implementation, so I can learn something too! If I understand correctly your main requirement is to be able to add/delete jobs without restarting the server. This needs to be emphasized along with other requirements, any possible constraints and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

What is your data store?

Here is one scenario... a little off the beaten path:

You can write a small console app (or similar) that is the "Job Populater".

You can wire it to pull job definitions from an xml file, and push them into ADO datastore (sql server).

Here is my quartz config to do this:

```
<quartz>

    <!-- 
    This configuration is a way to have jobs defined in xml, but will get them written to the database.
    See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589964/ramjobstore-quartz-jobs-xml-to-adojobstore-data-move/ 
    -->


    <add key="quartz.plugin.xml.type" value="Quartz.Plugin.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.plugin.xml.fileNames" value="~/Quartz_Jobs_001.xml" />
    <!-- 
    <add key="quartz.plugin.xml.ScanInterval" value="10" />
    -->

    <add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz"/>
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.dataSource" value="default"/>
    <add key="quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString" value="Server=MyServer\MyInstance;Database=QuartzDB;Trusted_Connection=True;Application Name='quartz_config';"/>
    <add key="quartz.dataSource.default.provider" value="SqlServer-20"/>

</quartz>
```

Which (as you see in the comments in the xml), I got help with.

Here is the original : 
[RAMJobStore (quartz_jobs.xml) to AdoJobStore Data Move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589964/ramjobstore-quartz-jobs-xml-to-adojobstore-data-move/)

Comment: Isn't it a bit redundant to be pulling jobs from xml and pushing it to the database when you are using AdoJobStore in the first place? Why not insert them directly into the QUARTZJOBS table and create a plugin that scans the table periodically and creates triggers?

Comment: @Circular Reference the method you are suggesting is what i wanted.But to implement i did not find proper documentation That is the problem.

Comment: We created the xml approach because our jobs (that need to be added) will grow over time.  The xml way allows (only the new jobs) to be "appended" to the database.  You could put the data directly in the QuartzDB, but I don't recommend it.  There is an API for a reason.  Code to the API and not the specific RDBMS on the back-end.  You can also wire up a SqlServer-CE for unit testing, which is another reason to use the API, not going directly.

Comment: @granadaCoder, You are right you should always code to the API, but my point was a bit different. You can have a separate table (call it QUARTZJOBS) and store your jobs there. Naturally, you use the API for scheduling jobs, creating/deleting triggers etc (see my answer). It seems redundant to me to combine stores, if most of your work will happen in ADOJobStore. You are going to incur the cost of using the database anyway; quartz server will effectively be scanning two places for jobs and triggers.

Comment: I have a console app called "PopulateNewJobs.exe", and this is the only thing that is coded to both datastores.  The main service ~only talks to one datastore (the ado one).  I agree, you don't want to have the main quartz/service talking to 2 datastores.  But we find this xml-append with the (new only) jobs to be good for deploying.