# Changing the jobcron without restarting the service

Tags: windows-services, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

Beginner:
We have a windows service build on top of quartz.net and we are using sql database to store the job cron. 
currently it is set to run the service once a day at 4.00 AM

we are getting no ideas as in how we can change the implementation, so that we can change the jobcron in the database and we dont have to restart the service and it picks it up automatically. will appreciate any help?

Comment: One way to do this is to use a plugin that updates your triggers automatically. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24321042/how-to-add-job-with-trigger-for-running-quartz-net-scheduler-instance-without-re/24374894#24374894

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a console app that reads XML-job-definitions and pushes them to the AdoNetStore.

See:

[RAMJobStore (quartz_jobs.xml) to AdoJobStore Data Move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589964/ramjobstore-quartz-jobs-xml-to-adojobstore-data-move)